# Is there a way to be aware of the execution of a 3rd party app?

Tags: android

Basically, I want to find out when another app starts, so I can adjust my app in a particular way. For example, if the user starts the GMail app, my service can detect that and react.

My current idea is to check 'topActivity' for each element in `getRunningTasks()` from the `ActivityManager` class. But that sounds quite expensive, since it needs to be constantly checking in the background (and I'm quite fussy about the CPU usage of my app).

If anyone knows a better way, I'd love to hear it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not way of doing that the "nice way" meaning a BroadcastListener since applaunch don't get broadcasted. The only way is to Start a service that checks the `getRunningTasks()`
*(For not to load the CPU too much you can also check what app is to the foreground. I'll search for the code if you are interested on that technic)*

Have the service checking at interval of 5-10 seconds. Also shut down the service at SCREEN_OFF and restart it at SCREEN_ON.

Sorry but there is no other way for that.

Comment: So basically, what I already had in mind. Hmm, thanks anyway!